# How to select specific parent box and select those children that belong to this children

Tags: javascript, html

I want to select specific parent box and select those children that belong to this children

```html
    <ul class="categories-list">
      <li class="category"><input type="checkbox" class='parent' id='1' onclick="toggle(this)"><label>Parent category</label>
        <a class='collapse-category' href=''>expand</a>
        <ul class="subcategories">
          <li class="category"><input type="checkbox" class='eztext' id='1' value='Child categoryad'>Child categoryad</li>
          <li class="category"><input type="checkbox" class='eztext' id='1' value='Child category44 '>Child category44 </li>
          <li class="category"><input type="checkbox" class='eztext' id='1'>Child category2332 ></li>
          <li class="category"><input type="checkbox" class='eztext' id='1'>Child category878 </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="category"><input type="checkbox" class='parent' id='2' onclick="toggle(this)"><label>Parent category2</label>
        <a class='collapse-category' href=''>expand</a>
        <ul class="subcategories">
          <li class="category"><input type="checkbox" class='eztext' id='2'>Child category2897</li>
          <li class="category"><input type="checkbox" class='eztext' id='2'>Child category26 </li>
          <li class="category"><input type="checkbox" class='eztext' id='2'>Child category2qs </li>
          <li class="category"><input type="checkbox" class='eztext' id='2'>Child category2,jhj </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

```
const checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll(".eztext");
const parent = document.querySelectorAll(".parent");

function toggle(itemId) {
    for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
        if (checkboxes[i] != itemId)
            checkboxes[i].checked = itemId.checked;
    }
}
```

I can only use vanilla JavaScript.

Comment: If you can, please get into the habit of (a) explaining what your code does presently, and (b) how you have tried to fix the problem you have, and (c) what problem you had in implementing that thing. You're much more likely to get good-quality help if readers see you have made an effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will use the ID of the parent checkbox to select only the child checkboxes with the corresponding ID. When you click a parent checkbox, only the child checkboxes under that specific parent will be affected.

```js
const checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll(".eztext");
    const parentCheckboxes = document.querySelectorAll(".parent");

    function toggle(parentCheckbox) {
        const parentID = parentCheckbox.id;
        const childCheckboxes = document.querySelectorAll(`.eztext[id='${parentID}']`);

        childCheckboxes.forEach((checkbox) => {
            checkbox.checked = parentCheckbox.checked;
        });
    }
```

```html
<ul class="categories-list">
    <li class="category">
        <input type="checkbox" class='parent' id='1' onclick="toggle(this)">
        <label>Parent category</label>
        <a class='collapse-category' href=''>expand</a>
        <ul class="subcategories">
            <li class="category"><input type="checkbox" class='eztext' id='1' value='Child categoryad'>Child categoryad</li>
            <li class="category"><input type="checkbox" class='eztext' id='1' value='Child category44 '>Child category44 </li>
            <li class="category"><input type="checkbox" class='eztext' id='1'>Child category2332 ></li>
            <li class="category"><input type="checkbox" class='eztext' id='1'>Child category878 </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="category">
        <input type="checkbox" class='parent' id='2' onclick="toggle(this)">
        <label>Parent category2</label>
        <a class='collapse-category' href=''>expand</a>
        <ul class="subcategories">
            <li class="category"><input type="checkbox" class='eztext' id='2'>Child category2897</li>
            <li class="category"><input type="checkbox" class='eztext' id='2'>Child category26 </li>
            <li class="category"><input type="checkbox" class='eztext' id='2'>Child category2qs </li>
            <li class="category"><input type="checkbox" class='eztext' id='2'>Child category2,jhj </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Now how do I make sure that the parent will be checked when I check all the child? If the child is not checked all then the parent should not be checked. Thanks!

Comment: @WinAung That is a new question. If you really want to know the answer to that then post another question and link back to this answer or your original question above.